# Elasticsearch Go nested query

Tags: elasticsearch, go, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-query

I'm using olivere's elastic Go library to run Elastic queries - https://godoc.org/github.com/olivere/elastic#NestedQuery

The data I'm trying to query on looks like this:

```
                "_source": {
                    "field1": "randVal1",
                    "field2": "randVal2",
                    "nestedfield": {
                        "ind1": "val1"
                    }
                }
```

I'm trying to run a query on the `nestedfield` using the `NestedQuery` call from the Elastic Go library like so:

```
aquery := elastic.NewTermQuery("ind1", "val1")
query := elastic.NestedQuery("nestedfield", aquery)
```

But I get an error stating:

> too many arguments to conversion to NestedQuery

I'm trying to retrieve all documents where the `ind1` of `nestedfield` is `val1`. Would appreciate any help in constructing this query.

**EDIT:**

I changed it to NewNestedQuery and now it doesn't give that error. However, it is not returning any results, even though that document exists in the index and I am able to query on the non-nested fields.

I tried this:

```
aquery := elastic.NewTermQuery("ind1", "val1")
query := elastic.NewNestedQuery("nestedfield", aquery)
```

And this:

```
query := elastic.NewNestedQuery("nestedfield", elastic.NewMatchQuery("nestedfield.ind1", "val1"))
```

But they both give 0 results. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT #2**

The mapping is:

```
"field1": { "type": "string" },
"field2": { "type": "string" },
"nestedfield": {
                    "type": "nested"
                }
```

What eventually worked was this:

```
query := elastic.NewMatchQuery("nestedfield.ind1", "val1")
```

I was able to add additional fields to 'nestedfield' and do queries like:

```
query := elastic.NewBoolQuery().Filter(elastic.NewMatchQuery("nestedfield.ind1", "val1"), elastic.NewMatchQuery("nestedfield.ind2", "val2"))
```

Comment: Share your mapping. I suspect that "nestedfield" is not actually a nested document.

Comment: I've adjusted answer below but you should try giving more detail of the full code used to search.

Comment: Shared mapping and what eventually worked

Answer (score 4):

Looks like that should be:

```
q := elastic.NewTermQuery("nestedfield.ind1", value)
nq := elastic.NewNestedQuery("nestedfield", q)
```

- NestedQuery is a type, not a function.
- NewTermQuery needs to take a
  value from the json, not a const string
- You'll need to parse your source json to get the value from ind1

Edited to fix NewTermQuery too as per comments below. If that still doesn't work provide the full code you're using to parse source and get the error as you don't give enough detail here to guess at the problem.

Comment: I tried this and the error went away but it doesn't return any results. I edited the question to add more details

Comment: `"ind1"`  should be `"nestedfield.ind1"`

Comment: I believe Val meant `aquery := elastic.NewTermQuery("nestedfield.ind1", val1)`

Comment: Thanks Val, Pandawan, I think you're right. Sorry for rejected edit.

Comment: I was able to use `elastic.NewMatchQuery("nestedfield.ind1", "val1")` to get the result. I wonder why the NewNestedQuery and NewTermQuery combo didn't work :/

Comment: With `olivere/elastic/v7`, this answer doesn't work, instead, `covfefe`'s comment work.s